# USA travel visa chennai

Tags: visas, usa, international-travel, travel-agents, chennai

Please recommend reliable travel agencies for USA travel visa. We are planning to invite my uncle & aunt (mom sister) for holidays, thanks

Answer (score 2):

Don't use any agency: just apply directly through the US consulate in Chennai.

[Click here for the application form](https://ceac.state.gov/genniv/). The visa they need is the B1/B2 visa, which, for Indians, is usually valid for 10 years (though less may be issued) and lets you stay for 6 months per visit.

Comment: Please advise best ways to establish their ties in India, Uncle and aunt 60 plus years , have only 1 son married settled in India. Uncle retired professor and aunty housewife. Thanks

Comment: A B1/B2 visa can be valid for one, five or ten years, they are not "usually valid for ten years".  The maximum time of validity varies from nationality to nationality.  And you are not guaranteed to get the maximum time of validity for your nationality.

Comment: @Tom "The maximum time of validity varies from nationality to nationality" I meant for Indians